# SQL join third table

Tags: mysql, inner-join

So I have a three table setup that looks like the following...

Table 1 - reciept items

```
ri_id | ri_name | ri_reciept 
----------------------------
1     | nails   | 1
2     | screws  | 1
3     | hammer  | 1
```

Table 2 - reciepts

```
r_id | r_name   | r_mop
-----------------------
1    | reciept1 | 1
2    | reciept2 | 2
3    | reciept3 | 2
```

Table 3 - method_of_payment

```
m_id | m_name
-------------
1    | Bank Transfer
2    | Cash
3    | Cheque
```

This is my SQL code im trying to run

```
SELECT * FROM reciept_items ri 
INNER JOIN reciepts r ON ri.ri_reciept = r.r_id 
INNER JOIN method_of_payment mop ON r.r_mop = mop.m_id 
WHERE ri_reciept = :id
```

UPDATE: Last WHERE line works like follows...

```
$queryRecieptItems = $dbh->prepare("
                SELECT * FROM reciept_items ri 
                INNER JOIN reciepts r ON ri.ri_reciept = r.r_id 
                INNER JOIN method_of_payment mop ON r.r_mop = mop.m_id 
                WHERE ri.ri_reciept = :id
            ");
            $queryRecieptItems->execute(array( "id"=>$reciept['r_id'] ));
```

I'm trying to access the 'm_name' column while looping through Table 1, any ideas why the above doesn't work?

Comment: What does the last line `WHERE ri_reciept = :id` do? BTW hi there! ^^

Comment: ill update question.

Comment: ha, iv just found my problem :) and Hi thanks for offering help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to prefix `ri_reciept` column in where clause with table name (although it should work without prefix) and pass the correct id in place of ":id", e.g. the below should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM receipt_items ri 
INNER JOIN receipts r ON ri.ri_receipt = r.r_id 
INNER JOIN method_of_payment mop ON r.r_mop = mop.m_id 
WHERE ri.ri_receipt = 1;
```

Here is the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4676d8/6/0)**.

Comment: Yes, it does, as long as there is no other table with same column name. I have updated the answer.

Comment: So this `:id` thingy is no part of mysql syntax i guess? ^^